# Как исправить баг со слайдером? последнее фото исчезает быстро

Tags: slider

```js
$(function(){
 //configuration
 var width = 1260;
 var animationSpeed = 1000;
 var pause = 3000; //auto interval
 var currentSlide = 1;
 
 //cache DOM
 var $slider = $('#slider__wrap');
 var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');
 var $slides = $slideContainer.find('.slide__item');
 
 var interval;
 
 function startSlider() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
   $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-=' + width}, animationSpeed, function(){
    currentSlide++;
    if(currentSlide === $slides.length){
     currentSlide = 1;
     $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0, 3000);
    }
   });
  }, pause);
 }
 
 function stopSlider() {
  clearInterval(interval);
 }
 
 $slider.on('mouseenter', stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);
 
 startSlider();
 
});
```

```css
#slider__wrap {
 width: 1260px;
 height: 230px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.slides{
 display: block;
 width: 6000px;
 height: 230px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.slide__item{
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 1260px;
 height: 230px;
 background: #ccc;
 
 img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 230px;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider__wrap">
    <ul class="slides">
    <li class="slide__item"><img src="img/bg/1.jpeg" alt=""></li>
    <li class="slide__item"><img src="img/bg/2.jpeg" alt=""></li>
    <li class="slide__item"><img src="img/bg/3.jpeg" alt=""></li>
    <li class="slide__item"><img src="img/bg/4.jpeg" alt=""></li>
    <li class="slide__item"><img src="img/bg/3.jpeg" alt=""></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Что за странный `img` внутри `.slide__item` в css? И почему ширина `.slides` меньше `.slide__item`x5?

Comment: )) это .slide__item img, просто я в sass писал стили

Comment: у .slides Общий блок растянут, а .slide__item задает конкретную ширину картинок. т.к. картинки зафлотины float:left в .slide__item

Comment: У вас 5 картинка не помещается в один ряд с остальными из-за маленькой ширины `.slides`, мне так думается.

Comment: пробовал, увеличивал ширину, все равно, последний <li > все равно резко заменяется на 1-ю картинку

Comment: Попробуйте на место последней картинки поставить первую :) (то есть на обоих концах ленты одинаковая картинка). Лента же у вас не бесконечная, из-за этого разрыв может возникать.

Comment: @Visman да сработало)) спасибо